# Как лучше изучать русский язык?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте! Я из Польши, и я изучаю русский язык. Я уже знаю его основы, но я не очень хорош в этом. Но, мне нравится, что русский язык настолько похож на польский. Не могли бы вы дать мне несколько советов о том, как лучше всего выучить русский язык? Большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Łukasz,

Вы сами писали этот текст? Если да, то вы достаточно хорошо владеете русским чтобы не задавать такие вопросы, а отвечать на них другим. )))

Самое правильное - идти тем путем, который предлагают ваши преподаватели. Единых советов на вашем уровне уже быть не может. А если вы занимаетесь самостоятельно, то просто работайте над темами, которые вам интересны, нужны по работе, учебе или еще как-то.

Вот вы сказали, что вам нравится русский за его сходство с польским. Попробуйте разобраться с этим с позиций сравнительной лингвистики. В чем именно сходство, в чем различие языков, есть ли к этому какие-то исторические предпосылки...

Но это все - факультативно. Живого общения с носителями языка и чтения ничто не заменит. Это для любого языка так.

Szczęścia i sukcesu!